# Retrieve specific chunk file from MongoDB gridfs

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I have stored 1.5GB video file to MongoDB GridFS using php script with Chunk Size 15MB.

I can retrieve the full video file using filename. But I wanted to skip chunk files and retrieve only specific part of the video.

Is it possible to skip and retrieve specific chunk files?

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: Possible? Yes. And it is so because GridFS is simply "software" as applied to the driver. From the database perspective each "chunk" is really just a "document" in a "collection", just like everything else you do in MongoDB. There are however likely wider issues here, as some good advice presented in an answer here alludes to.

Answer (score 3):

Although your requirement sounds simple at a glance, I believe its implementation is more involved than it looks, since if I understand correctly, what you want to build is essentially a video streaming system.

GridFS does not have a knowledge of the content of what you are storing. It is mainly a convention to enable you to store documents larger than 16 MB in MongoDB (larger than the maximum BSON size).

GridFS achieves this by splitting the input file into "chunks", but it is up to the application to make sense of the data in the chunks.

If you require specific part of a video by retrieving a specific chunk range, you would need to consider some things:

- Videos are frequently compressed using variable rate encoding (VBR), which means that one 15 MB chunk could contain varying minutes of video (e.g. could be 15 minutes in one chunk, could be 12 minutes in another chunk, etc.).
- Video files frequently contain a metadata part (e.g. title, synopsis, etc.). You would need to recognize this metadata part and separate them from the actual video packets. Most of the time, this metadata size is different from the video packet size.
- How granular is the "seeking" you want. E.g., if you require a 1-second seek granularity, you would need to calculate how much data is contained in a 1-second video. This could be calculated somewhat easier if you are using Constant bitrate encoding (CBR).

Hence, to achieve what you require, you would need to:

1. Encode your video using constant bitrate (CBR).
2. Be able to dissect the video format to be able to store one video packet in one chunk exactly.
3. Store the video metadata somewhere else.

Basically, this means that you would also need to construct the player that can understand this storage scheme to be able to "seek" into a certain point in the video reliably.

Comment: Hi Kevin, Just a question. We are compressing the video and store it. We believe that CBR will not work on compressed video. Is there any way to do the same in compressed video.

Comment: @Hari do you mean you compress the video using a general-purpose compression algo e.g. zip/rar? What was the original video format?

Comment: Video format is .mp4 and we are using codec(H264) compression method.

Comment: @Hari I need to clear up some things: 1) H264 is already highly compressed. You won't get much gain on compressing it with zip/rar/etc. 2) If you do, you're adding a complexity layer that is not doing anything other than making the video hard to play. 3) mp4 is a container format. The video, audio, subtitles etc. contents are compressed separately using their own scheme (e.g. H264 for video, AAC for audio). mp4 makes it possible to sync all those compressed streams and play them together.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. We are only doing H264 compression and not zip/rar/etc. Thank you for the info.